# This is confusing for me. Help! What material should I search?

Tags: absolute-value

Find the values of $x$ such that $|x-2|=2-x$. How do I solve this?

Comment: I would suggest you start by searching for the definition of absolute value.

Comment: Note that $2-x=-(x-2)$. Hence, this is equivalent to $x-2\leq0$.

Comment: How is x≤2 is true for every value of x? What principle is this?

Comment: By the definition of absolute value $|x-2| = -(x-2)$ when $x < 2$, and $|x-2| = x-2$ when $x > 2$. This is because only when $x-2<0$ does the absolute sign take effect and make the LHS positive.

Comment: Okay, took myself some time. But this really helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $t=x-2$. Then $|t|=-t$ is true for non-positive $t$. Hence $x-2\le0$.

---

More generally, and equation like

$$f(x)=\sum_k|a_kx+b_k|+ax+b=0$$

is piecewise linear, and it suffices to observe changes of sign between two "corner points", which occur where $x=-\dfrac{b_k}{a_k}$. You sort these points increasingly, including $-\infty$ and $\infty$ to cover the whole real axis, and evaluate the $f(x_k)$.

Here, with $f(x):=|x-2|+x-2$, the only corner point occurs at $x=2$, with $f(2)=0$. We have

$$f(-\infty)=0,f(2)=0,f(\infty)=\infty$$ so that $f(x)=0$ for $x\in (-\infty,2]$.

Answer (score 1):

As $|a|=\max(a,-a)\ge 0$, this means that $2-x\ge 0$, i.e. $x\le 2$.

Answer (score 0):

For $$x\geq 2$$ we get $$x-2=2-x$$ so $x=2$.
For $x<2$ we get $$-x+2=2-x$$ this is true for all $x$ with $x<2$.

Answer (score 0):

As $|x-2|\ge 0$, we must have $2-x\ge0$. And for all $x$ that satisfy this condition, we do have $|2-x|=2-x=|x-2|$.